# Calculate the diff of hours with momentjs in reduce method

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have an array with only hours. I want to calculate the diff between two hours, then add and subtrac these hours with 24.

This is my method:

```
  var total = this.itemsTurnos.reduce(function(anterior, actual, index) {
    let a = app.$moment(anterior.inicial, "HH:mm:ss");
    let b = app.$moment(anterior.final, "HH:mm:ss");
    var diffAB = b.diff(a, "hours");
    let c = app.$moment(actual.inicial, "HH:mm:ss");
    let d = app.$moment(actual.final, "HH:mm:ss");
    var diffCD = b.diff(a, "hours");
    return 24 - (diffAB + diffCD);
  });
  return total;
```

When the array have 2 index, the result is valid. But if the array have 1 or 3 or more, the result is NaN.

How can i fix it?

Comment: `No initial value, not updating accumulator.`

Comment: @CodeManiac with initial value return NaN

Comment: How your `this.itemsTurnos` looks like ? set initial value to `0` not as empty string ""

Comment: the array is: 
[{inicial: "00:03:55", final: "08:03:55"}, {inicial: "08:03:55", final: "14:03:55"}]
Also with 0 return NaN

Comment: I think i found my error... in the var diffCD, I use the ba diff instead dc diff... Nope.. added another index and return NaN again also with 0 as the initial value